# Confluent Kafka upgrade from 5.5.0 to 6.0.0

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible, confluent-platform

In our project we have install the confluent Kafka 5.5.0 version with cp-ansible https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible code through automation.
since this version already out of life so we are planning to upgrade with latest confluent Kafka version 6.0.0.

We are following this document https://docs.confluent.io/ansible/6.0/ansible-upgrade.html to upgrade confluent Kafka from 5.5 to 6.0.

We were able to upgrade the zookeeper node successfully but while upgrading the Kafka broker we are getting playbook error.

Zookeeper upgrade:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i /path/to/hosts.yml upgrade_zookeeper.yml
```

Kafka broker upgrade:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i /path/to/hosts.yml upgrade_kafka_broker.yml -e kafka_broker_upgrade_start_version=5.5.0
```

Please find the below error got while running the broker playbook.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i /path/to/hosts.yml upgrade_kafka_broker.yml -e kafka_broker_upgrade_start_version=5.5.0

Errors:
TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /automation/kafka-upgrade/confluent-kafka-downgrade/ansible/cp-ansible/cp-ansible/tasks/create_ordered_kafka_groups.yml:17
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'json'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/automation/kafka-upgrade/confluent-kafka-downgrade/ansible/cp-ansible/cp-ansible/tasks/create_ordered_kafka_groups.yml': line 17, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- set_fact:\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

Playbook code repo:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible/6.0.0-post/tasks/create_ordered_kafka_groups.yml

Comment: 1) I suggest you open a github issue in that repo... The error says there is a syntax issue in the YAML 2) You should upgrade to latest 6.x release, rather than just 6.0, which is end-of support in a few months  https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html